# How do you open an Rstudio project with a Git Bash command?

Tags: r, rstudio, git-bash

I am looking for a command to start an Rstudio project using Git Bash from the Git for Windows installation. I am looking for a command that opens the project in Rstudio, similarly to how it would open if you double-clicked on the .Rproj file in the Windows file explorer. I have Rscript.exe added to my PATH. Thanks!

Comment: Recognize that `.Rproj` files are for RStudio the IDE, not for R the programming language. R won't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add "C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin" to your PATH. This will give you access to rstudio.exe. You may then run `rstudio path-to-my-project.Rproj` in the bash command line, and it will open as desired in OP.

Edit: If RStudio is the default program to open .Rproj files, you can run `explorer path-to-my-project.Rproj`, and this will also open the project as desired.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS you can  use `open`, or on Linux `xdg-open`. E.g., `open path/to/your-project.Rproj`. See Connor's answer for Windows.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but `open` is not a command on a fresh install of Bash on Windows--that is for macos and linux? The command `start path/to/my/project.Rproj` does not open RStudio, either.

Comment: Ah, looks like you're right. I don't have a windows machine to test on. I'll edit my answer but leave it here as a reference in case people using MacOS or Linux find it.